# [React-Native]: No matching version found for @types/react-test-renderer@16.13.1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native, npm

I'm having issues trying to initialize a react-native project using the typescript template

I've followed the [instructions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) for windows targeting android. As it installs the dependencies, this pops up

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @types/react-test-renderer@16.13.1.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'awesomeproject'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\olive\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-10T10_39_02_715Z-debug.log
```

This is after running `npx react-native init AwesomeProject --template react-native-template-typescript`

checking out the log file, I get this:

```
3333 error notarget No matching version found for @types/react-test-renderer@16.13.1.
3334 error notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
3334 error notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
3334 error notarget
3334 error notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'awesomeproject'
```

I've tried initializing it using the default javascript template `npx react-native init AwesomeProjectjs` and it works with no issue.

I would like to use typescript. What could be the issue and how can it be solved?